# How can I horizontally align two Textviews without overlapping?

Tags: android, textview

I'm trying to put an N (new) badge at the end of the `Textview`. But Android Studio gives me that two `Textview`s, `hashtag_list_row_title` and `hashtag_list_row_new` can overlap if one `Textview` contains some lengthy string.

In production environment, it's not likely that `hashtag_list_row_title` is long, but I want to prevent two `Textview`s from being overlapped. How can I achieve this?

I prefer the way `hashtag_list_row_new` has priority over `hashtag_list_row_title` because that's more natural way to display an N badge.

So far my code is as follows.

#### list_row.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/hashtag_list_row_root"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_list_row_selector" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/hashtag_list_row_title_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/hashtag_list_row_post_count"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/hashtag_list_row_post_count">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/hashtag_list_row_title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:textColor="@color/hotspot_list_row_title"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:text="asdfasdfsadfsadfsfsfsafasdfsafsfasfasfasf" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/hashtag_list_row_new"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/hashtag_list_row_title"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/hashtag_list_row_title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@color/red"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="11dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="11dp"
            android:text="@string/N" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/hashtag_list_row_post_count"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/btn_post_normal"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:textColor="#787878"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/hashtag_list_row_divider"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/hashtag_list_row_title_layout"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:background="@color/bg_horizontal_divider" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

#### Edit

Textview on the right side should place right next to the left one, which has varying length. And I want to prevent the situation where the left one gets longer beyond certain length so that the right one is hidden, or overlapped, or whatever.

It should look as below.

| (text) N (empty space empty)|

| (more text) N (empty space) |

| (more text more more...) N  |

#### Edit 2

I want the left TextView to be ellipsized when it's beyond the width of the row except for N badge. I want this.

[image: good]

I don't want this.

[image: nogo]

#### Edit 3

N badge should not be placed on the right side all the time. I want the badge to be placed right next to the left `TextView` when the length is shorter than horizontal width.

It's good.

[image: good]

It's no go.

[image: nogo]

Answer (score 0):

Ran into the same problem.

What you want is the right side TextView to have:

```
android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/member_count"
```

The ID being the ID of the left side TextView.

```
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/member_count"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:text="10"
            android:textSize="16sp"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/member_count"
            android:text="Members"
            android:textSize="16sp"/>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try something like below.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/hashtag_list_row_root"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_list_row_selector"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/hashtag_list_row_title_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/hashtag_list_row_post_count"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/hashtag_list_row_post_count">

        <TextView
            android:singleLine="true" 
            android:id="@+id/hashtag_list_row_title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:textColor="@color/hotspot_list_row_title"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:text="asdfasdfsadfsadfsfsfsafasdfsafsfasfasfasf" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/hashtag_list_row_post_count"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/btn_post_normal"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:textColor="#787878"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:id="@+id/hashtag_list_row_new"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/hashtag_list_row_post_count"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@color/red"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="11dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="11dp"
        android:text="@string/N" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/hashtag_list_row_divider"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/hashtag_list_row_title_layout"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:background="@color/bg_horizontal_divider" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Result will be something similar like below. I had to remove some attributes that was pointing to resources that my project didn't have, so below figure is just a mock up. The code is updated to fit you.

[image: Reeult]