# Alling two Textviews without overlapping

Tags: android, textview, text-alignment

I'm trying to put a textView at the right side of another, but when i do it, the two textViews are overlapping:

This is what I want:

[image]

And that is what I don't want:

[image]

The same question is also asked here, but no finally solved: [How can I horizontally align two Textviews without overlapping?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28742385/how-can-i-horizontally-align-two-textviews-without-overlapping)

Comment: can u post ur xml code here, which helps to solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You need to give your xml It will greatly help.

But if you do it with the design tools (mouse click) 
Then move your textview near the border of the layout (on the right)

It will show a small arrow from the border to your textView2. And not from the textview1 to textView2